# SSAO incorrect at z = 0 and at distance

Tags: opengl, rendering, deferred-rendering, ssao

So I tried to implement SSAO, but it is not working as intended.
It seems to split at Position z=0 (worldspace), there is a white Line at position z=0. Also the Occlusion there doesn't look right.

[image]

Plus at greater distance, so when moving the camera, the occlusion becomes even weirder
[image]

My Shader to render the geometry (instanciated):

Vertex:

```
#version 330 core

 layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
 layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;
 layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexColor;
 layout(location = 3) in vec3 vertexNormal;
 layout(location = 4) in mat4 offset;
 layout(location = 8) in vec4 instanceColor;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 View;

out vec2 UV;
out vec4 Color;
out vec3 Normal;

void main()
{

        mat4 Model = offset;
    mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;



vec4 Pos = MVP * vec4(endpos,1);

gl_Position = Pos;

UV = vertexUV;

Color = instanceColor;
    Normal = normalize((Model * vec4(vertexNormal,0)).xyz);

}
```

Fragment:

```
    #version 330 core

    in vec2 UV;
    in vec4 Color;
    in vec3 Normal;

    uniform sampler2D Diffuse;

void main()
{
    gl_FragData[0] = vec4(Color);
    gl_FragData[1] = (vec4(Normal,1)+1)/2;
}
```

After the Geometry pass, I apply the SSAO pass with the Normal and Depth Information.

This is my NoiseTexture:
[image]

I use the hardware Depth Buffer.
I calculate everything in world space.

Here is the Fragment Shader:

```
    #version 330 core

#define KERNEL_SIZE 16
uniform sampler2D NormalMap;
uniform sampler2D DepthMap;
uniform sampler2D NoiseTexture;
uniform vec2 NoiseScale;

uniform vec2 Resolution;

uniform mat4 InvertViewProjection;

uniform float g_sample_rad = 0.1;
uniform float g_intensity = 2.0;
uniform float g_scale = 0.1;
uniform float g_bias = 0.0;

vec2 CalcTexCoord()
{
    return gl_FragCoord.xy / Resolution;
}

vec3 getPosition(vec2 uv)
{
    vec4 worldpos;

    float depth = texture2D(DepthMap, uv).r;

    worldpos.x = uv.x * 2.0f - 1.0f;

    worldpos.y = uv.y * 2.0f - 1.0f;

    worldpos.z = depth * 2.0f - 1.0f;

    worldpos.w = 1.0;

    worldpos = InvertViewProjection * worldpos;

    worldpos /= worldpos.w;

    return worldpos.rgb;
}

vec3 getNormal(vec2 uv)
{
    return normalize(texture2D(NormalMap, uv).xyz * 2.0f - 1.0f);
}

vec2 getRandom(vec2 uv)
{
    return normalize(texture2D(NoiseTexture, Resolution*uv / NoiseScale).xy * 2.0f - 1.0f);
}

float doAmbientOcclusion(in vec2 tcoord, in vec2 uv, in vec3 p, in vec3 cnorm)
{
    vec3 diff = getPosition(tcoord + uv) - p;
    vec3 v = normalize(diff);
    float d = length(diff)*g_scale;

    return max(0.0, dot(cnorm, v) - g_bias)*(1.0 / (1.0 + d))*g_intensity;
}



void main()
{

    vec4 Kernels[KERNEL_SIZE] =
    vec4[](
        vec4(0.355512,  -0.709318,  -0.102371,  0.0 ),
        vec4(0.534186,  0.71511,    -0.115167,  0.0 ),
        vec4(-0.87866,  0.157139,   -0.115167,  0.0 ),
        vec4(0.140679,  -0.475516,  -0.0639818, 0.0 ),
        vec4(-0.0796121,    0.158842,   -0.677075,  0.0 ),
        vec4(-0.0759516,    -0.101676,  -0.483625,  0.0 ),
        vec4(0.12493,   -0.0223423, -0.483625,  0.0 ),
        vec4(-0.0720074,    0.243395,   -0.967251,  0.0 ),
        vec4(-0.207641,     0.414286,   0.187755,   0.0 ),
        vec4(-0.277332,     -0.371262,  0.187755,   0.0 ),
        vec4(0.63864,   -0.114214,  0.262857,   0.0 ),
        vec4(-0.184051,     0.622119,   0.262857,   0.0 ),
        vec4(0.110007,  -0.219486,  0.435574,   0.0 ),
        vec4(0.235085,  0.314707,   0.696918,   0.0 ),
        vec4(-0.290012,     0.0518654,  0.522688,   0.0 ),
        vec4(0.0975089,     -0.329594,  0.609803,   0.0 )

    );
    vec2 uv = CalcTexCoord(); //same as UV Coordinate from Vertex
    vec3 p = getPosition(uv);
    vec3 n = getNormal(uv);
    vec2 rand = getRandom(uv);

    float ao = 0.0f;
    float rad = g_sample_rad / p.z;

    for (int j = 0; j < KERNEL_SIZE; ++j)
    {
        vec2 coord = reflect(Kernels[j].xy, rand)*rad;
        ao += doAmbientOcclusion(uv, coord, p, n);
    }
    ao /= KERNEL_SIZE;

    ao = 1 - (ao);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ao,ao,ao, 1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really following when you say z = 0. What coordinate space are you talking about? In NDC space that would be the center of your visible view and it'd be parallel to the image plane not running diagonal like the screenshot shows. In other spaces it could be your near or far clip plane for all I know. One thing I can tell you though is that a lot of that noise can be reduced if you use a linear / logarithmic depth buffer instead of perspective.

Comment: What works for me is a sort of hybrid approach. I use a floating-point depth buffer with inverted depth range (this sorts out some less than optimal precision distribution in perspective depth), which eliminates those banding artifacts and then various depth-based post-processing techniques actually require linear depth so I will also take the hardware depth buffer described above and linearize it as needed in the shader.

Comment: I calculate everything in world space, because my lighting is calculated in world space so I don't want to switch spaces.

to calculate my position in the world I don't need a linear depth. I tested it by sampling from a texture where I saved the position before and both give me the same result.

What I meant by z=0, that's the position in the world. If I move my camera towards z direction, and look at vertices which are farther away from z=0, they look distorted as shown in image 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by debugging the code step by step.

I calculate everything in world space. It's easier to handle everything there.
I looked at a tutorial which uses view space and changed everything I needed to world space.

The error is here:

```
 float rad = g_sample_rad / p.z;
```

this calculates the sampling radius based on the distance. In view space, this calculates the sampling radius for the distance from the camera.
But in world space, this calculates for the distance from the world coordinate, which resulted in it looking weird at z=0 and even weirder at farther away.

so what I did to fix that is simple this:

```
vec4 viewpos = CamView * vec4(p,1);
float ao = 0.0f;
float rad = g_sample_rad/viewpos.z;
```

I changed the point to view space and calculated the sampling radius in view space, thus taking in account the distance from the camera.

This fixes it.

[image]

I played a little bit with the g_values to fit them for my needs. See how it looks everywhere the same. That's what it should look like.